# How to use jQuery click function to track Google Analytics in an iFrame

Tags: jquery, google-analytics

I have an iframe (same domain), and want to be able to track the button usages inside the iframe from the parent page.

The reason I don't want to embed the tracking directly into the iframe is that I share the iFrame across different pages and want to be able to track it's unique usage by the parents page tracking events in jQuery.

Sample HTML inside the iFrame:

```
   <a class="btn1" href="1.html">button 1</a>
   <a class="btn2" href="2.html">button 2</a>
   <a class="btn3" href="3.html">button 3</a>
   <a class="btn4" href="4.html">button 4</a>
```

jQuery inside parent page :

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('.btn1').click(function () {
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'iframe page', 'iframe buttons', button 1]);
  });
  $('.btn2').click(function () {
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'iframe page', 'iframe buttons', button 2]);
  });
  $('.btn3').click(function () {
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'iframe page', 'iframe buttons', button 3]);
  });
  $('.btn4').click(function () {
  _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'iframe page', 'iframe buttons', button 4]);
  });
});
```

This isn't working though. If I view the parent page source, there's only the iFrame reference, none of the HTML - so I'm assuming that the parent page doesn't see any of the iFrames div classes to attached the click event?

I'm very new to jQuery... so apologies if I'm missing some gapingly obvious error!

**EDIT 1:**

I've now tried amending the script on the parent page to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('.iframe').contents().find('.btn1').click(function () {
  alert("Button 1 Pressed!");
  });
  $('.iframe').contents().find('.btn2').click(function () {
  alert("Button 2 Pressed!");
  });
  $('.iframe').contents().find('.btn3').click(function () {
  alert("Button 3 Pressed!");
  });
  $('.iframe').contents().find('.btn4').click(function () {
  alert("Button 4 Pressed!");
  });
});
```

and assigned the iframe the class="iframe".

When I click on the button inside the iframe from the parent page - no alert is triggered.

Comment: Reading through more generic iframe > jquery posts... I'm going to try adding a unique ID of '1' to the iframe, and target it like: $('#1').contents().find('.btn1').click(function () {_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'iframe page', 'iframe buttons', button 1]);});

Comment: Are the subdomains, domains, protocols and ports *exactly* the same, not just similar? They need to be; otherwise Same Origin Policy kicks in.

Comment: They are identical yahelc, called from the same domain, in the same folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone that stumbles across this thread and is looking for a similar answer - with the help of other stackoverflow posts (and some corrected code from: deantoni) and some long-winded Google threads, this was the solution that I came to that works.

The assumptions are:

- The iFrame is editable.
- Is under the same domain.
- You have the Google Analytics tracking code in the parent frame, with event tracking support.

The iFrame HTML used:

```
<a class="button1" href="1.html">button 1</a>
```

The iFrame jQuery used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('.button1').click(function() {
    window.parent.triggerButton1();
  });
});
```

The Parent Frame jQuery used:

```
    window.triggerButton1 = function (){
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'iframe page', 'iframe buttons', 'button 1']);
    }
```

Comment: There's no need for the `$(document).ready(function() {` on the parent frame.

Answer (score 0):

In the case that you are using an iFrame with the same domain/protocol and ports, you could use the jQuery Method `contents()`, this method can access the iFrame´s DOM and from there you can possibly do anything with it.

An Example would be:

```
$("#iFrame").contents().find(".btn1").click(function () {
   _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'iframe page', 'iframe buttons', button 3]);
}
```

You can find more about the `.contents()` method [here](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)

Comment: I've tried this, replacing _gaq.push with an alert - but clicking on btn 1 doesn't trigger the alert...

Comment: Could you pass a link so we can take a look and test out this case ? I tested the code above and it worked fine on a similar situation.